# Conditionally change the [Display(Name = "")] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple requirement but unable to understand how to achieve this. I have these properties in my View Model.

```
public class Feedback
{       
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Current ID")]
    public int? PreviousID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Next ID")]
    public int? NextID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ScenarioID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select you scenario")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YourScenario { get; set; }
}
```

Now on the view I have,

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourScenario, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ScenarioID, m.YourScenario, "Choose Scenario", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviousID, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PreviousID)
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NextID, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NextID)
   </div>
</div>
```

On the view as it can be seen that only PreviousID and a DropDownList for Scenario is displayed. Using JQuery I am showing and hiding the div for NextID based on some specific value of DropDownList. So suppose if user select "Scenario 3" from the dropdown then the Input for NextID is displayed.

Having explained all of this what I want is to change the Display name for PreviousID based on the selected value of dropdownlist. So if user selects "Scenario 1" and "Scenario 2" then the Display Name for PreviousID should be "Current ID" and if user selects "Scenario 3" then the Display Name should be "Previous ID". This change should also be reflected in the Validation Summary. So kindly tell me how to achieve this? Many Thanks

Comment: can you tell what have you tried

Comment: @Jigar Pandya I have already mentioned all the detail. What I have tried? Changing the inner content of the div through JQuery but this doesn't reflect in the error message displayed in the ValidationSummary.

Answer (score 3):

I have two ideas:

1)

You could remove the line `[Display(Name = "Current ID")]`. Then you need to use Label("SomeName") instead of LabelFor.
Then you create an event like DropDownList_SelectionChanged that then changes the Name of the Label.

2)

Or you add a member DisplayName and bind to it:

```
public class Feedback
{       
    [Required]
    public int? PreviousID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Next ID")]
    public int? NextID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ScenarioID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select you scenario")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YourScenario { get; set; }

    public String DisplayName {
        get 
        { 
            String name = "";
            if (ScenarioID == 1) {
                name = "SomeName";
            } else {
                name = "otherName";
            }

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
@Html.Label({Binding Content=m,Path=DisplayName}
```

It's probably not completely correct since I can not test your project but I hope you get the idea. Please tell me what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Let me try it. Will this work for validation messages too?

Comment: What do you mean with validation messages?

Comment: I am using Validation Summary on the view and the fields are required. So when user submit the form without entering the required values, a message is displayed in the validation summary that "Currrent ID is required". I was looking for a solution which changes Display Name so that it is updated for LabelFor and also in ValidationSummary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the `[DisplayName]` attribute, and instead use a `<label>` element manually in the view. Give the label an `id` e.g.

`<label for="whatever" id="lbl-whatever">Hello World</label>`

Create a JavaScript file that the view references, via a `<script>` tag, which uses jQuery to capture the change event of the dropdown

```
    $(function(){
        $("#ScenarioID").on("change", function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            console.log(this.value);

// I think this.id and this.value should display the id and value of the selected // item in the list.
            $("#lbl-whatever").text("Foo");
        });
    });
```

Hopefully the above should be enough to get you started.